# Change Desktop background without regedit

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Is there a way to change the desktop background of my Windows computer without editing the registry? Because this program will be running on different computers which might affect the Usb Drive Letter is there a vbs that will check to see what drive letter it is on and will copy the photo (I need the drive letter for the file origin to Copy it) to the local drive. Anyone know how to do this? TIA

Comment: `Wscript.ScriptFullName` contains the full name of your vbs file so just get the drive letter from it.

Comment: No, you can't change the wallpaper without modifying the registry, since it's the place where the wallpaper location is stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a powershell script file set_desktop_background.ps1

```
Push-Location
cd HKCU:\
Set-Itemproperty -path 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'WallPaper' -value ''
add-type -typedefinition "using System;`n using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`n public class PInvoke { [DllImport(`"user32.dll`")] public static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, int[] lpaRgbValues); }"
[PInvoke]::SetSysColors(1, @(1), @(0x663309))
Start-Process "taskkill.exe" -ArgumentList "/F /IM explorer.exe" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
Start-Process "explorer.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden
Pop-Location
```

And then invoke it via

```
powershell -File C:\desktop_background\set_desktop_background.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to edit the registry and this is by definition of how the image is referenced.

As the commenters above have mentioned, there are ways to get around this concern. For one, you could try a relative path instead of absolute. In the below code, of course remove the messagebox.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
msgbox WshShell.CurrentDirectory 'This returns the path of your script
```

To get the full path to your script, simply use

```
msgbox WScript.ScriptFullName
```

For bonus points, we could use

```
msgbox CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

This would negate any concern about drive letters or wherever the folder is. If you want, you could use the below to pull the drive letter.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strPath = objShell.CurrentDirectory
strDrive = objFSO.GetDriveName(strPath)

msgbox strDrive
```

Something that would complicate your script is that you want to ensure the desktop picture is still available after the flash drive is removed. You have two options. One, you can copy your picture to a safe location on C:. Or, what I would do is add a listener in the VBS that checks to see if X: drive is still readable. Once the flash drive is unplugged, the vbs will keep running so it will notice the drive is gone and will then change the desktop image back.

Some psudocode:

```
Read the reg desktop location
Back it up
write new location
refresh desktop
Call Secondary Script (OR LOOP NOW to watch the drive)
```

Depending on what your script does, have it call another script that checks for the flash drive, or simply have a loop in the main script. I would simply call another script so your free to do whatever else in the main one. Let me know if you have any more questions!